# Best technology for keeping navigation between web pages

Tags: php, javascript, html, asp.net, css

I am fairly new to web development and I have been researching as to what would be the best method to reuse the navigation/banner in multiple web pages, but I have been unable to find a conclusive answer.

**What I want to do:**
[image]

The website content will be almost entirely static. I do not need CMS or anything like that. It is a very simple site.

**What I want to know:**

What is the best method of keeping the banner/navigation but changing content?

- HTML + CSS? There seem to be a few different ways to achieve it with
  this; such as using Server Side Includess or hiding pages with CSS.
- Using JS/jQuery
- ASP.NET Master pages. This currently seems like the best method, although it seems like overkill for such a basic site.
- PHP: Such as an include the header in each page.
- Something else?

So what is the best option for keeping the navigation between pages?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: This question doesn't belong to StackOverflow. You should to try [Programmers, by StackExchange](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/). What a pity because it's a very well written question. :(

Comment: There's no best single option. JS/jQuery will break hot-linking to specific pages unless you use HTML5 History API or the hashbang hack. PHP includes are usually fine and give less trouble, but it is up to your necessities.

Comment: frames, Dreamweaver templates, or SSI are among the simplest options that have the fewest limitations and complications.

Comment: don't use frames, don't use frames, don't use frames

Comment: @Dagon: what's so bad about frames? they provide SEO, accessibility, and work in just about everything...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a really simple site, create a template page, `template.php`, create folder for your content, then for every page in your site, specifiy the content you want to include and then include the template.

E.g.:

```
//template.php
<?
  if( !isset $pageTitle ) $pageTitle = 'Hello World';
  if( !isset $pageContent ) $pageContent = 'content/home.php';
?>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><?php echo $pageTitle ?>
    // add css links here
  </head>
  <body>
    <? require_once($pageContent) ?>
  </body>
</html>

// index.php
<?
  $pageTitle = 'My Home Page';
  $pageContent = '/content/home.php'

  require_once('template.php');
?>

// content/home.php
<h1>Welcome to my site</h1>
```

I use a system like that quite often, if I don't want to use one of the large complicated CMS/Template engines that's already out there.

This code probably wont work if you copy and paste, it's just a rough example

Comment: Using php seems to be the most common answer. It looks to be pretty basic to implement too. So I will accept your answer as the best. Thanks!

Comment: It's free, open source, there are many libraries to help, lots of other developers you can talk to, it's a good place to start, and there are lots of huge sites that run on PHP. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

This question is going to get closed because it's too opinion-based, but I'll give you my opinion.

If you are a .NET shop, I'd use MasterPages. MasterPages give you the benefits you're looking for, and if your website grows more complex in the future, MasterPages have benefits other than maintaining a similar markup across a site, like sharing methods and Controls that all the child pages may access.

If you're not a .NET shop, and you truly don't think this site will ever get complex, stick with server-side includes in HTML and CSS.

Answer (score 1):

If your web site is completely static, I would opt for server side includes / shtml.  PHP includes would also work well.  ASP.NET Master pages are fine, but what server are you running on?  For public consumption, the cheapest solution usually works out to be apache (hence either shtml or php).

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply have the same header in all the pages.  Whether you use PHP or not is irrelevant.  Since you say your site is simple, this might be the best and easiest option.

Using anything like AJAX (js) to dynamically load content is likely overkill for a simple site. But there is no right or wrong answer.